# CSS - fixed side nav should scroll / move if not fully visible

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have a site with a fixed header and fixed side nav, and scrolling content.

I've found that on some pages, users with smaller screens can not access all the menu items as the fixed side-nav extends off the bottom of their screen.

Is there any way round this?

I did a quick mockup to illustrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/cr0wn3r/ycTXF/

It's all fine till you shrink your browser, and then you see the leftcol goes off the bottom of the screen and there is no way to scroll to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using media queries, you can detect the size of the viewport, and then conditionally style your sidebar accordingly (perhaps placing it after all the content if the height of the viewport is too small).

[This article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) by Ethan Marcotte explains well what you can achieve with responsive sites, while [this site](http://mediaqueri.es/) demonstrates how different viewports can be handled.

The key is to use media queries to handle different viewports correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this. I'll have a good read. Unless Im missing something though it's not going to solve the issue for IE7 and I still have to support that.

Comment: You can always use respond.js for legacy IE support of media queries: [https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably used media queries to change the styling of your fixed nav for users with smaller screens. Smaller font-size, padding, whatever.

There is a great article by Chris Coyier explaining CSS Media Queries here http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this. I'll have a good read. Unless Im missing something though it's not going to solve the issue for IE7 and I still have to support that.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of the solution to add

```
    overflow: scroll;
```

To your CCS (I've done this on your fiddle). It's ugly but otherwise your visitors have to buy new screens...
Or maybe you can just adjust the font-size?!

Comment: hmmm. Well I could live with ugly, but when I add overflow:scroll it doesnt work as the div doesnt seem to be aware that it is hanging off the bottom of the screen. So the hidden content just stays hidden. Maybe it would work if I fixed the height of the nav div, but I'm not sure I want to do that as then I'd have to set a small size just to cater for a few users, and even users with big screens would have to scroll the menu.